# Unable to resolve javax.transaction.xa partial=true

Tags: osgi, apache-commons, apache-karaf, apache-commons-dbcp

I am trying to use dbcp2 from apache-commons to setup a datasource, but I cannot install commons-dpcp2 bundle because it is complaining about a missing requirement javax.transaction.xa package version>=1.1.0 mandatory:=partial; partial=true.

This exact version is installed in the runtime via karaf's transaction feature (on 4.2.1) (albeit WITHOUT the mandatory:=partial;partial=true directive or flag or whatever you wanna call it)

So it appears I cannot install dbcp2 and use it without hacking... Anyone have a "normal" solution to this problem or i have to tear my shirt open like Conan and repackage dbcp2?

Also if anyone from apache packaging stumbles upon this , why you gotta package it in such a "funny" way??? Why append these make-shift flags that ultimately do nothing?? Quit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What a coincidence ;) - It's fixed and explained by https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KARAF-6715

Comment: In theory though , this flag shouldn't be on the dbcp bundle. It's up to ME how I manage MY runtime and what bundles provide what packages, javax.transaction.* or whatever. Strictly from dbcp's perspective this is or should be irrelevant... "I need packag X version X.X from API" is all it needs to declare... Assuming package X is defined in a standard API

Comment: I agree, DBCP2 should better manage OSGi manifests, but from my experience, I know that lots of libraries add "OSGi support" as one-time contribution from OSGi community, and then it stays as is...